# Not able to get with relationship data after the joining table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I'm building an app on Laravel, where I'm having a model named `ConstructionProduct` something like this:

```
class ConstructionProduct extends Model {

    protected $table='construction_product';

    public function productDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ConstructionProductDetails::class, 'construction_product_id', 'id');
    }
    
}
```

Table `construction_product` has columns: `id`, `created_at`...

Then I've `ConstructionProductDetails` model something like this:

```
class ConstructionProductDetails extends Model {

    protected $table='construction_product_details';
    
     public function constructionProduct()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ConstructionProduct::class, 'construction_product_id', 'id');
    }

    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class, 'construction_product_brands', 'const_product_details_id', 'brand_id');
    }
}
```

Table `construction_product_details` has columns: `id`, `construction_product_id`..

I've a table `construction_product_project` with column name: `id`, `construction_product_id` and `project_id`
also I've another table `constrution_product_brands` with column name: `id`, `const_product_details_id` and `brand_id`

I'm trying to execute the below query:

```
return ConstructionProductDetails::whereHas('brand', function ($q) use($id){
        $q->where('construction_product_brands.brand_id', $id);
    })
    ->with('brand')
    ->paginate();
```

this gives me the brand relation, but when I join `construction_product_projects` I'm getting null or empty brand list. bellow is my query:

```
return ConstructionProductDetails::whereHas('brand', function ($q) use($id){
        $q->where('construction_product_brands.brand_id', $id);
    })
    ->join('construction_product_projects', 'construction_product_details.construction_product_id', '=', 'construction_product_projects.construction_product_id')
    ->with('brand')
    ->paginate();
```

I think it is contradicting with `brand_id`. How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Could you try and put your `join` before the `whereHas` and see what happens?